# jBPM 6.4.0 workbench code compliance level

Tags: jbpm

Running jBPM 6.4.0 on Windows: Creating a Data Object from the KIE Workbench and attempting to "Build & Deploy" my project, I'm getting errors on the annotations that have been automatically added to the data object definition source code.

> Error: "Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater"

Java 8 (1.8.0_77) is installed and JAVA_HOME environment variable is pointing to the installed location.

Is there a way to set the code compliance level? I've looked through the KIE Workbench and project settings and don't see a way to set the compliance level.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!search/Syntax$20error$2C$20annotations$20are$20only$20available$20if$20source$20level$20is$201.5$20or$20greater/drools-setup/rK373aE2GD0/kF-xXuorAwAJ) upgrading WildFly will handle the issue...

"...Note that I'm now using wildfly-9.0.2.Final because on wildfly-8.2.1-Final I cannot build the optaplanner-playground code because I have a lot of:

`Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater`..."